# Is it possible to customly rewind mp3 X seconds on s40?

Tags: java-me, mp3, midp

I've been trying to find out if it's possible to customly rewind X  mp3 seconds, without any luck.

Additional  feature I want to implement in my player is to play mp3 from "xx:xx" (specified time).  Couldn't find any documentation describing that either.

My player uses Manager/Player classes,  MIDP 2+

please help

thank you

Answer (score 1):

How about this approach using [`getMediaTime`](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/media/Player.html#getMediaTime%28%29) and [`setMediaTime`](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/media/Player.html#setMediaTime%28long%29)?

```
private void rewind(Player player, int seconds)
    throws MediaException 
{
    long now = player.getMediaTime();
    long before = now - (1000 * seconds);

    if (before > 0) {
        player.setMediaTime(before);
    }
}
```